# How to dynamically specify file path in Karate multipart file?

Tags: karate

I need to upload a file to a specific endpoint, but I have a couple of different files for each different environment I'm testing the endpoint in. I have a file structure similar to this:

```
src
|
+-- java
|  |
|  +-- test.feature
|
+-- resources
|  |
|  +-- dev
|  |  |
|  |  +-- file.txt
|  |
|  +-- qa
|     |
+     +-- file.txt
```

So I thought to assign the environment to a variable and use it to indicate the file path in the multipart-file step:

```
And multipart file file = { read: "classpath:#(environment)/file.txt", filename: 'file.txt', contentType: 'multipart/form-data' }
```

However, when I tried this, Karate didn't seem to actually replace `#(environment)` with the proper variable, as I expected it to:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: #(environment)/file.txt
```

I also tried to use the Karate `replace` functionality, but that failed for me as well.

Is there any other way to specify a file path like this in Karate?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

So try this:

```
 * def filename = 'classpath:' + environment + '/file.txt'
 And multipart file file = { read: "#(filename)", filename: 'file.txt', contentType: 'multipart/form-data' }
```